# Transparent activity in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am using transparent activity in order to display caller id above incoming call screen.When transparent activity starts, I am not able to communicate with the background activity(caller screen).Is it possible to display a transparent activity above another activity (say Activity A)and interact with Activity A without finishing transparent activity?

This what I am currently using,

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>

<item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
```

And in my onReceive method of receiver,

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {   

         @Override
         public void run() {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             Intent intent = new Intent(context, CallerIdActivity.class);
             intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
             context.startActivity(intent);
         }
     }, 2000);
```

Comment: It sounds like the transparent activity should be a fragment of Activity A.

Comment: But, in my case, activity A is Android's inbuilt call screen

Comment: http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/, note that this probably won't work on all devices.

Comment: @dst: Thanks mate.Do you know on which devices it wont work? Is it API level related issue? Or device specific issue?

Comment: As you are indirectly opening the Activity in transparent mode so It will work like simple activity only. You can not simultaneously interact with another activity from your transparent activity. You will have to finish it.

Comment: @BasimSherif from what I heared some device-specific extensions like Sense, TouchWiz, ... cause issues in some cases. For the API level, consult the android docs. I have not tried these features personally yet, nor I tested them on a wide range of devices.